# Make DateTimePicker work as TimePicker only in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to restrict `DateTimePicker` to select the time only? I don't know how to disable calendar control which drops when you press the button at the right of `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

A snippet out of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx):

> 'The following code sample shows how
> to create a DateTimePicker that
> enables users to choose a time only.'

```
timePicker = new DateTimePicker();
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

And for anyone who wants to know what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Ha, the solution was simple: just set datetimepicker's ShowUpDown property to true and set Format to DateTimePickerFormat.Time. Only setting Format to DateTimePickerFormat.Time is not enough.

Answer (score 49):

...or alternatively if you only want to show a portion of the time value use "Custom":

```
timePicker = new DateTimePicker();
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
timePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm"; // Only use hours and minutes
timePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Comment: If you use this route and you need to specify AM or PM you can add `tt` to the string. Full list of format options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 15):

You want to set its 'Format' property to be time and add a spin button control to it:

```
yourDateTimeControl.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
yourDateTimeControl.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it from properties, you can do this by setting the `Format` property of  `DateTimePicker` to `DateTimePickerFormat.Time` and `ShowUpDown` property to `true`. Also, `customFormat` can be set in properties.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is this:

```
datetimepicker.Format = DatetimePickerFormat.Custom;
datetimepicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
datetimepicker.ShowUpDowm = true;
```

Comment: I like how you added the "tt" to custom format so we can choose AM or PM

Answer (score -2):

Add below event to DateTimePicker

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This language definitely doesn't look like C#. Also, you should explain what that code does. How it disables changes of date, but preserves changes of time.