# Display date and time range

Tags: json, vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker

I want to display **date and time** from the selection of **datetimepicker** *start date* and *end date*:

[image: Click image Here]

I tried several ways and search on the web but still cannot find the solution. Output I would like to get is:

[image: Click image here: refer to timeStamp]

the **timeStamp** will display the **date** and **time** from the **datetimepicker** and will increasing the time until the end date that user picked.

my code:[my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qlrg.png)

Please anyone who can help me, i would really appriciate it.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593686/make-datetimepicker-work-as-timepicker-only-in-winforms

Comment: Use a `Do` or `While` loop.  Inside the loop, call `AddHours` or whatever is appropriate to the time increment you want.  Start at the start date/time and continue until you pass the end date/time.