# c# Winform DateTime Show Time only in Datagrid

Tags: c#

Hello and thanks for your time

I have a DateTime Picker that populates to a DataGrid. The problem I'm having is I want the time only, preferred (Military Time). I have tried .ToString .TimeOfDay and so on. I think the last line of code(today.year,month,day) is the issue but don't know how to correct it.

```
 var start_time = dateTimePicker1.Text;
 var start_time_array = start_time.Split(':');
 var today = DateTime.Now;
 var trailer_count = Convert.ToInt32(tbTrailer_Needed.Text);
 var minutes_apart = Convert.ToDouble(tbTime_Between.Text);
 var calculated_start_time = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 
     today.Day, Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[0]), 
     Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[1]), 00);
```

Comment: Try `ToString("hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: That gives me errors on my last line of code.

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593686/make-datetimepicker-work-as-timepicker-only-in-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. For now do you string conversion on a different line to better identify if you have an error in that first lie.

```
var calculated_start_time = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 
     today.Day, Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[0]), 
     Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[1]), 00);
string time = calculated_start_time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

But it's not exactly clear what you wish to accomplish. If I understand correctly the following is an option you might want to consider. Set the datetime picker to show only the time https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx

```
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
```

Then I think the following should work but I cant test it right now.

```
string dateTimeYouWant = DateTime.Today.Add(DateFromTimePicker.TimeOfDay);
```

You might not even have to do anything as DateFromTimePicker might already be based on today but I'm not sure.

========edit=====

Things you need to know.

1. To get the value from a dateTimePicker you should use .Value and not .Text, .Value will return a DateTime and that's what you want to work with.
2. To get "Today" you should use DateTime.Today and not DateTime.Now. DateTime.Today will will have the minutes, hours etc set to zero.

   3. If you are new I would avoid using var and would give the real type.

now lets look at your code

```
    var start_time = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    var start_time_array = start_time.Split(':');
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var trailer_count = Convert.ToInt32(tbTrailer_Needed.Text);
    var minutes_apart = Convert.ToDouble(tbTime_Between.Text);
    var calculated_start_time = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 
     today.Day, Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[0]), 
     Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[1]), 00);
```

Lets remove those 2 lines that have no impact on your problem

```
    var start_time = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    var start_time_array = start_time.Split(':');
    var today = DateTime.Now;       
    var calculated_start_time = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 
     today.Day, Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[0]), 
     Convert.ToInt16(start_time_array[1]), 00);
```

You want to replace all that code by this:

```
DateTime calculated_start_time = DateTime.Today.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

And to make it even better configure your datetimepicker (at the init of the form or the property editor) so your users cant chose a date but only a time:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Comment: Yes i want to show time only but dont know what line to add it to. I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: i have added .Value , .Today and set to Ture. it still returns 12/3/16 8:28 in the datagrid.

Comment: Got it awesome info, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateTimePicker.Value` and `DateTime.TimeofDay`:

```
var calculated_start_time = DateTime.Today + dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeofDay;
```

Comment: Value no extension method,   Cant understand it this hard to show Time only in the DataGrid