# Disable date chosing in DateTimePicker winform

Tags: winforms

I finding a timespan control in `winform`, but it's seem `winform` does not support it or I don't know that.
I use `DateTimePicker` but I don't want `date` be showed, therefor I wanna Disable date chosing in `DateTimePicker winform` like that :

[image]

Please guide me to disable it or any `timepicker` control

Comment: [Make DateTimePicker work as TimePicker only in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5593686/8967612)?

Comment: @41686d6564 YES

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make DateTimePicker work as TimePicker only in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593686/make-datetimepicker-work-as-timepicker-only-in-winforms) If so, then confirm a duplicate. You should see a notice somewhere at the top of your question.